# Replace method call to another

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.0

I need to replace all the ocurances of `obj.Method1()` to `obj.Method2()` where `obj` is an instances of the same class. Does ReSharper or VS2010 allow this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd cheat - Do a 3-point symbolic rename (Right-click->Rename on a method name)

- Method1 -> Temp
- Method2 -> Method1
- Temp -> Method2

None of this will change code functionality but will update all your code to use the correct name, except the methods themselves are now named incorrectly - simply rename the methods to by hand and *voila* - A little bit hacky but fast and effective.

This does rely on all method calls being in managed code (so that VS knows how/what to rename). If you have XML comments, C# rename handles this well but VB doesn't - I assume since you mention ReSharper, you're using C#?

This also assumes the method signatures are identical (if not, get ready for a lot of copy/pasting)

Comment: ReSharper's support for VB is getting close to it's support for C#, at least in a lot of ways.

Comment: I thought about this but was hoping there was something like "Replace method call" action either in VS or R# :)

Comment: @Dan I wsan't aware of that - been a while since I've tried it in VB, I'll have to give it another spin

Answer (score 7):

You could write a **ReSharper Replace Pattern** (*ReSharper->Tools->Pattern Catalog*, *Add Pattern*) like so:

[image]

where the type of expression *obj* needs to be changed to your class (that contains *Method1*).

Then press ***Save*** and thereafter press ***Search now*** to get all *Method1()* calls:

[image]

Then click ***Replace*** and all *Method1* calls are type-safely replaced to *Method2*.

Answer (score 0):

Make body of Method1 like this

```
public void Method1(...) { return Method2(...); }
```

And invoke refactoring "Inline method" on Method1.

Comment: Good idea but in my case I need to keep both methods without replacing theirs functional.